# How to add value to an existing key

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using a loop statement to add keys and value in the map from a result set and if the key already exists, update that key and add to its value.

This is my code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> item_id = new Hashmap<Integer , Integer>();

for (i=0 ; i<roomtype_id.length(); i++) {
  String query ="SELECT item_id , quantity from amenities_tb where roomtype_id = '"+roomtype_id.get(i)+"'"
  PreparedStatement pst = connection.preparedStatement(query);
  Result Set rs = pst.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()) {
    if (item_id.containskey(rs.getInt(1))) {
      // update this key and add to its existing value
    }
    else {
      item_id.put(rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2));
    }
  }
```

Comment: `item_id.put(rs.getInt(1), item_id.get(rs.getInt(1)) + rs.getInt(2))`

Answer (score 4):

In java 8 you can make the full if else just a single statement:

```
item_id.compute (rs.getInt (1), (key, old) -> (old == null ? 0 : old)+rs.getInt (2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the old value from the map, add the value to it, and put it back in the map.

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> item_id = new Hashmap<Integer , Integer>();
   for(i=0 ; i<roomtype_id.length(); i++)
   {
      String query ="SELECT item_id , quantity from amenities_tb where roomtype_id = '"+roomtype_id.get(i)+"'"
      PreparedStatement pst = connection.preparedStatement(query);
      Result Set rs = pst.executeQuery();

      while(rs.next()){
                if(item_id.containskey(rs.getInt(1))){
                    // update this key and add to its existing value
                    int value = item_id.get(rs.getInt(1));
                    value += rs.getInt(2);
                    item_id.put(rs.getInt(1), value);
                }else{
                          item_id.put(rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2));
                }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you but why did you assign the value to the item_id?

Comment: I didn't assign anything to `item_id`, that is the name of your map. I would suggest a more meaningful name like `idMap` or `quantityMap`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
  while(rs.next()){
            if(item_id.containskey(rs.getInt(1))){
             Integer value = item_id.get(rs.getInt(1));
             if(value == null) 
               value = 0;
              item_id.put(rs.getInt(1), value);
                      // update this key and add to its existing value
            }
  item_id.put(id, previousValue + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to make your value a collection eg:
`Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

or a simpler solution would be to use google guava library:
`Multimap<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: I think OP means integer addition, not add the value to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can use `merge`:

```
Integer key = rs.getInt(1);
Integer value = rs.getInt(2);
item_id.merge(key, value, Integer::sum);
```

Also, make sure that `key` and `value` are **Not Null**

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is
>   associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.
>   Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given
>   remapping function, or removes if the result is null.